# Default Implementation swfitリファレンス

Tags: swift

swiftのリファレンスで、プロトコルのメソッド等の説明で、Default Implementation　と記述されている箇所がありますが、これは何を意味しているのですか。

Protocol Extensionsが使われているという意味でしょうか？

要件が満たされたとき、protocol Extensionsで記述したものが採用されるとは、
どういった記述でできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

例えば、[`CollectionType`のソースコード](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift)を見てみると、ドキュメントのDefault Implementationsのところに記述されている`map`は、[`CollectionType`の`extension`として実装](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L309)されています。

特定の要件が満たされた時にだけProtocol Extensionを有効にするには、`extension`定義時に`where`で要件を指定します。例えば、[`generate`のデフォルトの実装](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L206)は、以下の様な形で定義されています。

```
extension CollectionType where Generator == IndexingGenerator<Self> {
  public func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<Self> {
    return IndexingGenerator(self)
  }
}
```